# SSD in RAID trouble

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, ssd, raid

My Debian system suddenly stopped working. When I rebooted, I saw errors before entering crypt password `failed to IDENTIFY after ACPI commands`

```
mdadm: device 1 in /dev/md/1 has wrong state superblock, but /dev/sdc3 seems ok
```

and afterwards `RAID status not OK. Exiting. ... failed!`

also after booting the system up `smartctl -i /dev/sdc` returned

```
User Capacity:        600 332 565 813 390 450 bytes [600 PB]
Logical block size:   774843950 bytes
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=47 offset=50 bd_len=46
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

When I reboot again, I get this message `mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2)`,
`mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2)`
however this time the output of `smartctl -i /dev/sdc` seems OK

```
User Capacity:    128 035 676 160 bytes [128 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Contents of `/proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sda3[0] 
  124716928 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
md0 : active raid1 sda2[0]
  249664 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
unused devices: <none>
```

How to make sure the SSD is working and get the RAID working properly?

UPDATE: `/sbin/badblocks -v -s /dev/sdc` returned 0 errors, so there seems to be no HW problem

Comment: What type of RAID is it even? RAID0? What’s in `/proc/mdstat`? Also, replace your SATA cable. If intermittent errors still occur, either the SSD or the SATA controller is defective.

Comment: RAID1, /proc/mdstat Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sda3[0]
      124716928 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md0 : active raid1 sda2[0]
      249664 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>

Comment: Please include that information is your question. You can’t have proper formatting in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have connected the SSD the right way, so as to not burn any of the pins or damage them.  I would start there if you have just set this system up.

Comment: It has been running for almost 2 years and the laptop is sitting on a desk connected to peripherals and it has not even been moved in last 2 months or so

Comment: Do you have the necessary drivers for AHCI support?  Can you boot into the BIOS?  Which BIOS version are you running?  It seems that you have not ran any SMART tests yet on your drive.  As far as I can tell, you have ran the SMART test to indicate whether or not SMART is enabled with the /i switch, but, other than that have yet to proceed with the testing.  I would run the test in the foreground using sudo smartctl -t <short|long|conveyance|select> -C (this indicates foreground) /dev/sdc  You can run the short test first if you so choose.  Length of time determined by sudo smartctl -c /dev/sdc

Comment: Use this website for some useful AHCI commands, though I haven't searched in detail..I've only really seen battery functions/CPU temp...nothing about parsing or _GTF http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/using/acpi

Comment: I'd like to run the SMART test, but because of SMART Error Log not supported I'd have to use stdout to display the results and it seems there is no such option

Comment: sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc is what returns your SMART Error Log not supported ?  If not, that is the switch that should display results.

Comment: Yes, I ran smartctl --all /dev/sdc

Comment: of course as sudo

Comment: Well, I think I need to know more specs of your system.  Start here and try and apply any relevant information https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/smartctl-does-not-report-any-smart-attributes.13937/  and then we can work on gaining something and deducing an answer.

Comment: I don't use Linux, so I am just trying to figure it out through Google.